# Set Navigation Bar below Toolbar in Marshmallow 6.0

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I have tried many answers on stackoverflow but couldn't solved the navigation drawer problem for marshmallow devices. 
[This is the screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i37bi.png)

On pre marshmallow devices, the issue is solved using this line.

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

I need help. I have four files generated by Android Studio

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_deal_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_deal_screen"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_deal_screen_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/content_deal_screen"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="com.immacbytes.foodyum.dealScreen"
 tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_deal_screen">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.immacbytes.foodyum.dealScreen">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppHomeScreen.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppHomeScreen.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_deal_screen" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
 android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
 android:gravity="bottom"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

this works but when you run it on api below < 20 it keeps some space and that is my problem how to solve this problem

```
 android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to your NavigationView too.